# Android Webview video capture Gingerbread

Tags: android-webview, android-camera, video-capture, android-2.3-gingerbread, webviewclient

I'm trying to use video upload using Video Camera in Android 2.3.6 GingerBread using Android Webview in Eclipse.

But i couldn't get it. Please help me out.

This is working properly in later versions except GingerBread

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you mean using an <input type=file > control with the capture attribute set?

Comment: Yes.. But in android 2.3, the capture attribute cannot be used.